# ListView - keep specific item in view when soft keyboard appears

Tags: android, listview, scroll, android-softkeyboard

In my app I have an activity with a ListView in the lower half of the display.  There are other UI elements above it, which can be used to add items to the listview.  The client indicates that he wants the newly added items to be automatically scrolled into view - this is fine and `setSelection(position)` works fine for it.  However when the soft keyboard then appears, the screen is resized (I have `android:windowSoftInputMode=adjustResize` in the manifest), the physical size of the listview decreases and the newly added item is no longer visible.

Essentially, when the listview resizes, it keeps the first visible item in place - whereas I need to force it to keep the last visible item in place.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: have you solved your problem?

Comment: @PozzoApps No, I haven't. I had to convince the client that it's technically impossible